# underline when writing text in entry view - xamarin,forms android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

When I write text in entry view in xamarin.forms I alway have underline under the text

I search all the web for a solution - it was to change the background to null or transparent BUT its not working.

is there any other solution ?

Comment: Are you asking how to enable underlining?  Or are you saying it is already underlining and you want to disable it?  Can you post a picture of the behavior you are trying to fix?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but it seems to get viewed/asked a lot, and Xamarin *still* hasn't added built-in support for customizing this very basic UI feature, so I will post an answer here that will hopefully be helpful. Also most answers you will find online (including the Microsoft documentation) show you how to create a static custom renderer, but what we really want is a control where we can set properties in shared code like with any other control. I figured out how to do this so I will share here. I've also included a property for setting border color and width since this is a common UI element we like to set.

In your **shared project** create a class called CustomEntry (you can rename this later if you wish).

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CustomizedControl
{
    public class CustomEntry : Entry
    {
        public Color BorderColor { get; set; }
        public int BorderThickness { get; set; }
        public bool HasUnderline { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In your **Android project** create a class called CustomEntryAndroid and paste in this code:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using CustomizedControl;
using CustomizedControl.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryAndroid))]
namespace CustomizedControl.Droid
{
    public class CustomEntryAndroid : EntryRenderer
    {
        public CustomEntryAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
        { }
        private bool HasUnderline;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var element = (CustomEntry)Element;
                HasUnderline = element.HasUnderline;
                var BorderClr = element.BorderColor.ToAndroid();

                if (HasUnderline == false)
                {
                    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                    gd.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                    Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd); //this is depreciated but it doesn't matter, the new method SetBackgroud simply calls SetBackgroundDrawable
                } //Else maintain default underline

                if (BorderClr != Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent)
                {
                    int borderThickness = element.BorderThickness;
                    if (borderThickness == 0) { borderThickness = 1; } //in case border thickness was not set then default to 1
                    var brdr = new ShapeDrawable(new Android.Graphics.Drawables.Shapes.RectShape());
                    brdr.Paint.Color = BorderClr;
                    brdr.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
                    Control.Background = brdr;
                    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                    gd.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                    gd.SetStroke(borderThickness, BorderClr);
                    Control.SetBackground(gd);
                }
            }//end if

        }//end OnElementChanged

    }//end public class CustomEntryAndroid
}//end NameSpace
```

You can now use the custom entry in any xaml page and get rid of the underline like this:

```
<local:CustomEntry HasUnderline="False" />
```

Here is a very simple content page with pretty much nothing on it but an entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomizedControl"
             x:Class="CustomizedControl.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Padding="30">
        <local:CustomEntry Text="Test text" WidthRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="Start" HasUnderline="False" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Note the import statement `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomizedControl"`. Here is the output:
[image: no underline]

Now with the underline attribute set to true:

```
<local:CustomEntry Text="Test text" WidthRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="Start" HasUnderline="True" />
```

[image: with underline]

And finally with a border:

```
<local:CustomEntry Text="Test text" WidthRequest="250" HorizontalOptions="Start" BorderColor="Purple" />
```

[image: with border]

Notice I did not specify a width in the xaml but the border still appeared. This is because I set the default width to 1 in the Android custom renderer. But you can set the width thicker like this `BorderThickness="6"` or modify the default behavior if you wanted to.

One final note: the namespace I used for this project is "CustomizedControl", so you will of course need to replace "CustomizedControl" with whatever your namespace is.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant answer. In the same breath I am trying to change the cursor color. Do you think that is possible?

Comment: You're welcome @PholosoMams ! Unfortunately I have no idea how to change the cursor color, never tried it. Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here

http://geeks.ms/xamarinteam/2015/04/20/branding-a-xamarin-forms-app-on-android-accent-color/

Your ask was a little obscure, but I think the link above can help you ... you just need to set the underline color for all status as same to the background or transparent.

in Android 5.0 devices, which use the specified accent color you can just change the color, another hand, in androids 4.< you need to create an image